# Create a hyperlink of a slanting image in expression Blend

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I am developing a navigation menu in silverlight that has 6 images. As you mouseover each image grows and clicking on an image will take you to a page on the website. The customer I am doing this for decided that straight rectangular images were boring and I showed him a design where I have slanted each image so each one is now a rhomboid shape. Horizontal top and bottom with sides slanting about 30deg from vertical.

I have been unable to figure out any way of growing each image on mouseover without putting a white block over the adjacent images. Would be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are PNGs with Transparency, why are you getting white blocks?

Normally the only issue to worry about is Z-order if adjacent options get larger, which you can fix by parenting all the buttons on a canvas and animating the Z-order as well as the scale.

Hope this helps.